# ¿Por qué me sale el error commandError: 'C:/Users/Escritorio/Bank_be//authApp' already exists?

Tags: python, django-admin

Estoy utilizando este comando para que se cree la carpeta migrations, es el siguiente:

```
django-admin startapp authApp
```

Sin embargo, tengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por qué sale éste error? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: ¿Por qué sale ese error y cómo puedo solucionar?

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, tienes ese error porque estás creando una carpeta que ya existe, esa carpeta ya se ubica en tu proyecto. Podrías crear otra carpeta o bien utilizar la que ya tienes:

```
django-admin startproject myProyect
cd myProyect
```